# Comment a code on pycharm without pushing to git

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, documentation-generation

I would like to post my own comments and understandings into a code, where I don't want these comments to be pushed to the repo.

I'm not sure if this is possible, currently, I'm creating a local notebook to explain some things in the codebase and add additional context.

So is it possible to just add notes instead of comments or comments where it's not pushed to the codebase somehow?

Comment: You can stage everything, then unstage those lines with your comments. But you'll have to keep doing this all the time on each commit. Perhaps someone else has a better idea...

Comment: I thought about that. But it seems to be too much work. I'm not sure if pycharm should support such a feature. As in many cases comments pushed to the repo should have a certain format and sometimes it's just better for you to add comments for your own understanding

Comment: One solution would be to copy these files and rename them to <file>_with_notes and then add this to the gitignore with *_with_notes. Of course this might lead to confusion. But you have your comments locally and can still work in the right files as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution when after further investigation and trying different solutions.

In PyCharm, the following useful free extension adds notes to your code where it's visible as comments but doesn't interfere with your commits, and it is saved to a local folder where you can sync with a separate git repo.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17874-private-notes

[image: https://gitee.com/The-Blind/private-notes/raw/master/doc/show.gif]